# I am getting File SyntaxError: invalid syntax for line 13 self = self.trieDict[word[0]]

Tags: python, trie

I am writing code to insert words into a trie data structure and then search the words. I am getting invalid syntax error for line self = self.trieDict[word[0]] (3rd line in the insert function)

```
#Trie data structure
class TrieNode():
    trieDict = {}
    isComplete = False

    def __init__(self, dic, isComplete):
        self.trieDict = dic
        self.isComplete = isComplete
    
    #self is the root node
    def insert(self, word):
        while len(word) != 0 and self is not None:
            if word[0] in self.trieDict:
                self = self.trieDict[word[0]]
                word = word[1:]
            else:
                child = self.TrieNode({}, False)
                self.trieDict[word[0]] = child
                self = child
                word = word[1:]
            self.isComplete = True
    
        def search(self, word):
            while len(word) != 0 and self is not None:
                if word[0] in self.trieDict:
                    word = word[1:]
                    self = self.trieDict[word[0]]
                else:
                    return False
                return self.isComplete
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: While the line is very strange in what it does, there is no error in the syntax.

Comment: Hard to see, but code is actually `self = \x13self.trieDict[word[0]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied the following line from your code

`self = self.trieDict[word[0]]`

an unrecognized symbol is right in front of the second `self` that is causing your syntax error. (It seems to be Unicode 0013) Simply delete it or rewrite the line on a new line and remove the offending line.

On a sidenote, assigning to `self` in a method is usually not a good idea as it points to the instance on which you are executing the method. While not syntactically incorrect, it will definitely cause confusion to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code after correction (for inserting nodes into a trie and searching nodes in the trie:

```
class TrieNode():
    trieDict = {}
    isComplete = False
    
    def __init__(self, dic, isComplete):
        self.trieDict = dic
        self.isComplete = isComplete
        
    #self is the root node
    def insert(self, word):
        current = self
        while len(word) != 0 and current is not None:
            if word[0] in current.trieDict:
                current = current.trieDict[word[0]]
                word = word[1:]
            else:
                child = TrieNode({}, False)
                current.trieDict[word[0]] = child
                current = child
                word = word[1:]
            current.isComplete = True
        
    def search(self, word):
        current = self
        while len(word) != 0 and current is not None:
            if word[0] in current.trieDict:
                current = current.trieDict[word[0]]
                word = word[1:]
                
            else:
                return False
        return current.isComplete


def test():
    node = TrieNode({}, False)
    node.insert('cat')
    node.insert('car')
    node.insert('pod')
    print(node.search('car'))
    print(node.search('ccar'))
    print(node.search('pod'))
    print(node.search('pode'))
test()
```